# What is a Lovely Word™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Lovely Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Lovely Words™,Not Lovely Words™
ARTFUL,CLUMSY
CLARINET,VIOLIN
CZARDOMS,KINGDOMS
FEMINISM,MISOGYNY
IMMUNITY,VULNERABLE
LIAR,HONEST
LITERALISM,UNEDUCATED
MIMICS,REAL
MISLODGE,REMOVE
MUNCHKIN,DONUTS
NUGGET,CHICKENS
RACISM,RACIST
SCARCITY,ABUNDANT
SWIVET,SWIVEL
TYRANNIC,EVIL
VICINITY,SURROUNDINGS
YEARNS,DESIRE
ZINC,GOLD
```

Addition 1:

> ***A.*** I've found a second answer to the problem, one that I do not want. I will put some counter-examples here.
> The following words are Not Lovely Words™: AW, BOWL, CARS, QUEENS. 
>  ***B.*** In the chart, MUNCHKIN is listed as a Lovely Word™. This is disputable.

Addition 2:

> In the chart, MISLODGE is listed as a Lovely Word™. Whether or not this is disputable is disputable.

Hint 1:

> All Lovely Words™ will have an even number of letters. All listed counter examples also have an even number of letters to give you more to work with.

Hint 2:

> Try the following: 
>  - Can you find the abnormality in one of the Lovely Words™? 
>  - Can you find the two letters with mutual everlasting love? 
>  
> The rule isn't complex, although it's not exactly as simple as a doornail. You could determine whether or not a word is a Lovely Word™ by staring at it for perhaps ten seconds.

Comment: The fact that Lovely Words are ordered alphabetically is relevant?

Comment: Nope. That's just for style.

Comment: Is it too early to give hints?

Comment: I think yes, it's too early to give hints.

Comment: One thing I've noticed, which is unlikely to be a coincidence: all of the words have an even number of letters.

Comment: I added something. It might or might not help.

Comment: I just found an awesome property of ARTFUL, but it must be coincidence as it doesn't work with the others :-/

Comment: What is this awesome property that thou speakest of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EDITED to replace a wrong answer -- thanks, greenturtle3141 -- with what I hope is now a right one.]

I think a word is Lovely (tm) when

> it is made up of a succession of *compatible pairs* of letters, where two letters are compatible if, when written as capitals, they are homeomorphic (i.e., topologically equivalent).

This depends a bit on

> the typeface used; in particular, G may either be homeomorphic to a single line or have a bifurcation. Clearly here the latter is the case because it occurs in a pair with E.

This criterion is almost equivalent to

> counting the number of "ends", but note that B and O both have no ends but fail to be homeomorphic (they have different numbers of loops; a topologist would observe that their fundamental groups or first homology groups differ). Similarly for A/R (which have loops) versus, say, C (which doesn't).

Lots of things are disputable because of

> serifs. E.g., does I have two or 4 ends?

The abnormality mentioned in the second hint is

> in the word MISLODGE, where the G is actually in a different typeface or something of the kind -- compare it with the ones in NUGGET. (That should have been a hell of a giveaway and I'm annoyed I didn't notice it until writing this.)

Perhaps the letters with "mutual everlasting love" referred to in the second hint are

> P and Q, the only two letters with just one end, which can therefore only ever occur with one another.

Or they might be

> D and O, which are the only two homeomorphic to circles. These, unlike P and Q, can actually occur next to one another in a word.

Comment: And here I was thinking the everlasting pair was A and R because they are only paired with each other in the lovely words.  As a note I did a word search for P and Q together and I don't think there are any words where they are together.

Comment: Truly one of the all-time great tragic loves. Can't bear to be apart, but never able to be together.

Comment: But "O" has no ends

Comment: @Bohemian "B" and "D" also have no ends.

Comment: This is extremely close and I upvote. In Addition 1, I put counterexamples such as BOWL to refute this specific solution that I was scared of. It's not exactly the number of ends, but something similar and slightly mathematical.

Comment: OK, how about now? My apologies for not noticing the counterexample.

Comment: 